# How to bind to a field of a static class in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any way that I can bind to a field in a static class in windows phone 7?

In WPF I can write something like

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static local:TestStatic.Items}}" />
```

where TestStatic is defined as

```
public static class TestStatic
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Items
    { get { return new string[] { "Item A", "Item B", "Item C" }; } }
}
```

but this doesn't work in WP7, the error is "The type 'x:Static' was not found. ...".

Does anyone have any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Why don't you do this in code behind? `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` and in code behind `this.listbox.ItemsSource=TestStatic.Items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the static markup extension in WP7 (which I find quite annoying). You will need to go with a workaround such as the one abhinav suggested.

Comment: It kind of sucks to have to do this in code behind - especially as Microsoft are always telling us that xaml is the solution to everything.

Comment: I know what you mean. Lately I find myself slowly slipping back into my old WinForms habits :(